# How can I get return value from multiple processes in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, return-value

I want to get return values from multiple processes initialised in one function and started in another function.

```
 import multiprocessing
 import time

 class Auto:

    def __init__(self):
        self.msf = 0

    def auto(self, return_dict, i):
        # print "hello"
        return_dict["hello"] = "hello{}".format(i)

    def msf1(self):
        man = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.return_dict = man.dict()
        self.a= multiprocessing.Process(target=self.auto, args=(self.return_dict, 1, ))
        self.b= multiprocessing.Process(target=self.auto, args=(self.return_dict, 1, ))
        self.c= multiprocessing.Process(target=self.auto, args=(self.return_dict, 1, ))

    def msf2(self):
        self.a.start()
        self.b.start()
        self.c.start()

        return self.return_dict.values()
```

Comment: You could return them via a queue

Comment: Can you illustrate with code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Queue()` to collect items from multiple processes. [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Here is a very simple example of how it can work.  See [this part](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#examples) of the docs for a more in depth example of how it works.

```py
def number(done_queue):
    done_queue.put(5)

done_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
x = Process(target=number, args=(done_queue))
x.start()
x.join()
y = [i for i in done_queue]
print(y)
```